# Solving the diophantine equation $6x^2 + y^2 + 6x = 3xy + 6y + x^2y$

Tags: diophantine-equations

> We have $x,y$ belong to integers satisfying the condition
> $$6x^2 + y^2 + 6x = 3xy + 6y + x^2y.$$
> We need to find the solution for which $y$ is maximal.

By trial I get $x=4$ , $y=30$. Which matches the answer. However I am looking for subjective approach. I made a quadratic with respect to $y$ but things got messy.

$$y^2 - y(6+x+x^2) + 6x+6x^2$$
We need to have discriminate to be perfect Square

$$ D = (x^2 + x + 6)^2 -4(6x+6x^2)$$
However this is in 4th degree which I don't know how to handle

Still $$ p^2 = (x^2 + x + 6)^2 -4(6x+6x^2) $$
Using $$ (x^2+ x + 6 - p)(x^2 +x+ 6 + p) = 24( x + x^2 )$$

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933) (edit your post to include your attempts, even if they failed), and [format your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Please explain what a subjective approach is.

Comment: $y\mid6x(x+1)$ and $x\mid y(y-6).$

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%246x%5E2%2By%5E2%2B6x%3D3xy%2B6y%2Bx%5E2y%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aintegers%2C%20OR%20content%3Amaximal&p=1), there's the AoPS thread [CNCM Online R2P6](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h2227032p16973406).

Comment: Rakesh Bothra, if you add more context to your post and write in detail what you tried, your attempts and efforts, I will help you to solve your exercise.

Comment: The quadratic w.r.t. $y$ is incorrect.